# Custom RestTemplate with CA and client certificates without importing crts to jvm keystore

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

I have a Spring Boot app with a custom `RestTemplate` which loads client cert from file (from resource folder).

How can I now also add CA certificate (PEM file) to this `RestTemplate` as well from file? (or any other way to achieve the goal with spring boot?)

```java
@Bean public RestTemplate restTemplate() ... {

  SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
          .loadTrustMaterial(new URL(clientCert), str.toCharArray()).build();
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
  CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory).build();
  ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
  return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I came across some code that could be of help in your use case.

It is available at Github under MIT license at [this repository](https://github.com/rfreedman/android-ssl).

The important artifacts are defined in [this package](https://github.com/rfreedman/android-ssl/tree/master/src/main/java/com/chariotsolutions/example/http).

Basically, the library proposes a helper class named [`SSLContextFactory`](https://github.com/rfreedman/android-ssl/blob/master/src/main/java/com/chariotsolutions/example/http/SSLContextFactory.java).

This class defines a method for creating a `SSLContext` with a client certificate, its password, and the corresponding CA certificate, the last one from a cert file, named [`makeContext`](https://github.com/rfreedman/android-ssl/blob/87c606d65233242480f0d20ade0ba110ffe1d990/src/main/java/com/chariotsolutions/example/http/SSLContextFactory.java#L39-L52), copied here for convenience:

```java
public SSLContext makeContext(File clientCertFile, String clientCertPassword, String caCertString) throws Exception {
  final KeyStore keyStore = loadPKCS12KeyStore(clientCertFile, clientCertPassword);
  KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
  kmf.init(keyStore, clientCertPassword.toCharArray());
  KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();


  final KeyStore trustStore = loadPEMTrustStore(caCertString);
  TrustManager[] trustManagers = {new CustomTrustManager(trustStore)};


  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
  sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);


  return sslContext;
}
```

As you can see, it uses different helpers methods and the helper class [`CustomTrustManager`](https://github.com/rfreedman/android-ssl/blob/master/src/main/java/com/chariotsolutions/example/http/CustomTrustManager.java).

Please, be aware that the solution is quite dated but I think it is still suitable.

Then, use the the `makeContext` method when constructing your `RestTemplate`:

```java
@Bean public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    SSLContextFactory sslContextFactory = SSLContextFactory.getInstance();
    SSLContext sslContext = sslContextFactory.makeContext(clientCert, str.toCharArray(), caCertPem);
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory).build();
    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

If your PEM file contains a certificate chain, you can modify the `loadPEMTrustStore` method defined in `SSLContextFactory` by something like this:

```java
private KeyStore loadPEMTrustStore(String certificateString) throws Exception {
  try (InputStream certificateStream = certificateString.getBytes()) {
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = 
      CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    // note the change in the method, we use generateCertificates
    Collection<X509Certificate> certificates = 
      (Collection<X509Certificate>) 
      certificateFactory.generateCertificates(certificateStream);
  
    KeyStore trustStore = 
      KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(null);

    String alias;
    for (X509Certificate certificate : certificates) {
      alias = certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
      trustStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, certificate);
    }

    return trustStore;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I have a certificate chain in my PEM file? Should it also be uploaded like KeyStore trustStore = loadPEMTrustStore(caCertText); or I have to make something like an array with multiple instances/objects of something? Cuz in your decision it decode only pem files containing one begin-end section. So, the problem is either in loading method, or it is supposed to work with chains at all...

Comment: You are welcome @VictoriaAgafonova. I updated the answer with a possible solution to the cert chain use case. I personally have never tested it in the context of SSL, but I used a similar code in others. I hope it helps.